# Why is the inf-convolution of lower semicontinuous functions continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity, convolution, proof-explanation

I'm confusing now about the continuity of inf-convolution.

I understand that the inf-convolution of lower semicontinuous functions is semiconcave and so it's locally Lipschitz continuous (in particular, continuous.)
However, if one consider a jump function like
$$
f(x)=1\quad(\text{for $x<0$}),\quad=0\quad(\text{for $x\ge0$}),
$$
then the inf-convolution of this function is clearly discontinuous at $x=0$.
I don't know why this difference occurs.

Please teach me about this contradiction or my wrong.
Thank you for comments.

---

**Added**

The inf-convolution I'm saying is
$$
f^{\varepsilon}(x)=\inf\left\{f(y)+\frac{|x-y|^{2}}{\varepsilon}\right\}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming $\epsilon >0$ here.

You have $f^\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x < -\sqrt{\epsilon} \\
{x^2 \over \epsilon}, &-\sqrt{\epsilon} \le x < 0 \\
0, & 0 \le x
\end{cases}$, which is continuous.

Comment: I realized that I misunderstood thanks to your answer. Thank you so much.